# How do I add the current webbrowser url to this type of string in Visual Basic?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I've been trying to fugure out how to get the current url of the webbrowser for this string: `Dim t As String = client.DownloadString("browserurl")`

```
'defining it like this didn't work, it ended up with error, and I also tried a few similar options. 
Dim browserurl As String = WebBrowser1.Url.ToString
'this didn't work either
Dim browserurl = WebBrowser1.Url.AbsolutePath
'neither did this...
Dim browserurl As New StreamReader(WebBrowser1.Url.AbsolutePath)

        Dim client As New WebClient
        Dim t As String = client.DownloadString("browserurl")
        Dim p As String = ""
        Dim r As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(p)
        Dim v As String = reg.Match(t).Value
```

What I'm trying to do is to parse data from websites the webbrowser visit and the URL cannot be the same since I need it to work on multiple urls I visit.

Comment: What has this to do with VBA? In VB.Net, use the `webBrowser1_Navigated` to get the current URL. You may want to see [THIS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.url.aspx) . Also `client.DownloadString("browserurl")` Here `browserurl` is treated as a string and not a variable. You may want to see [THIS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadstring(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your reply!

Comment: I have also tryed this: `Dim siteUri As New Uri("WebBrowser1.Url.ToString()")

        Dim client As New WebClient
        Dim temp As String = client.DownloadString("siteUri")`                                But the problem is that I only get a piece of the address like "/home.html" and then I get a error message

Comment: Please read my first comment again :) I am off to bed. It is already 4:36 AM in this part of the planet.

Comment: Yes, I have done it. I know how to make it show the current url on for eg. a label when using the Navigated state. But incorporating it together with the line is hard for me since I barely know the basics in VB :(

Comment: I dont suppose its possible to add this sub inside the navigated sub?

Comment: client.DownloadString("browserurl") Here browserurl                what do you mean by "here browserurl"?

Comment: So nobody knows how to fix this??